# IIS 6 gives directory listing unavailable in MVC 2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I have inherited an MVC 2 application and we are constantly getting 404 errors and directory listing unavailable errors. I have tried adding in the additional routes suggested by the forums to get around the issues in IIS 6, but we still get the error. The other baffling thing is that the error doesn't happen consistently. We have tried to replicate it while debugging with no success, we have also run load tests on the app and it functions fine under load. I have gone through the code and there is nothing obviously wrong with it, it does use session, and viewdata variables extensively, however the values being stored are small and shouldn't be an issue. Like I say I am at a loss to explain why this is happening. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

IIS 6.0 doesn't support extensionless urls out of the box. Checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) for configuring.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but unfortunately we have already looked into that. I forgot to metion that there is another site running on the same server that is also using MVC 2 which doesn't ever give these issues. The only difference is the app I am managing is configured to display different content based on the host header.